# Remove part of an email address

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have emails like `sales@joebloggs.com`.

I am looking to select out everything after the `@` and before the `.`.

Result should be `joebloggs`.

Comment: Maybe this is a weird idea, but isn't separately storing the local and the domain part of the address easier if you don't always want the entire address? I'd call one field 'email_local' and the other 'email_domain'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regex pattern should do the job.

```
SELECT regexp_matches('sales@joebloggs.subdomain.com', '@([^.]+)\.');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8820)

Edit: fixed to support subdomains. I assume you want to get the part before first dot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `substring` and `position`:

```
substring(col from (position('@' in col)+1)
              for (
                  position('.' in substring(col from (position('@' in col)+1))) - 1
              )
          )
```

Comment: @hvd Please review my updated answer.  And it is clear why regex is the way to go here.

Comment: Your updated answer looks as good functionality-wise as can reasonably be expected. You can simplify slightly by getting rid of the `for (char_length(col) - position('@' in col))`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using substring and instr

SELECT 
substring('sales@joebloggs.com', instr('sales@joebloggs.com', '@') + 1, instr('sales@joebloggs.com', '.') - (instr('sales@joebloggs.com', '@') + 1)) 
FROM dual;